# no puedo usar el session storage

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function prueba() {
    let name = document.getElementById(ejemplo);
    sessionStorage.setItem("usuario", name);
  }

  function mostrar(){
      alert(sessionStorage.getItem("usuario"));
  }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="StyleIndex.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="ejemplo" placeholder="pon algo aqui .-.">
        <button class="btn" id="crear" onclick="prueba()">crear</button>
        <button class="btn" id="crear" onclick="mostrar()">mostrar</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Este código es un ejemplo del código real que estoy haciendo,
básicamente lo que quiero es que una usuario llegue y ponga cierta info. para que se almacene en el session storage después de presionar un botón y en un texto se muestre (en este ejemplo una alerta) lo muestre después de presionar un botón, ya lo intente pero me sale Null en vez de la palabra que escribo en el input type text.
La pagina que estoy haciendo es una agenda de trabajos pendientes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás tomando el `<input>` en forma de nodo, tienes que leer su propiedad `.value`

```js
function prueba() {
  let name = document.getElementById("ejemplo");
  // Otro error: "ejemplo" no está definido, tienes que ponerlo en un string
  sessionStorage.setItem("usuario", name.value);
}

function mostrar(){
  alert(sessionStorage.getItem("usuario"));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ejemplo" placeholder="pon algo aqui .-.">
<button class="btn" id="crear" onclick="prueba()">crear</button>
<button class="btn" id="crear" onclick="mostrar()">mostrar</button>
```

`sessionStorage` al igual que `localStorage` solo admiten valores que sean de tipo **string**, de otro modo no lo guardarán

Comment: gracias, me has ayudado muchisimo

Comment: @PolloVolador Si una respuesta te ayuda, no olvides [marcarla como aceptada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3761/consejos-sobre-c%c3%b3mo-usar-el-sitio/3762#3762), esto recompensa tanto a la persona que te ayudó como a ti y también sirve para que otros usuarios con el mismo problema sepan llegar a la solución. También puedes leer [¿Qué significa cuando una respuesta es "aceptada"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)